# Криптографически безопасно ли заполнять инициализационный буфер хеш-функции случайными значениями?

Tags: криптография, случайные-числа, хеширование

У многих хеш-функций есть буфер, заполняемый по определённым правилам. Безопасна ли его единоразовая замена случайными данными такой же длины?

Comment: Но если его заполнять случайными данными то итог рассчета хеш функции каждый раз будет случайным. Т.е. хеш функция перестанет быть таковой, а станет еще одним генератором случайных чисел

Comment: @Mike, имеется в виду единоразовая замена буфера (или вектора, если правильно понимаю) в коде хеш-функции.

Comment: От функции зависит. Как по мне, так большинство криптографических хеш функций должны быть не чувствительны к этому ибо их алгоритм заведомо односторонний и отличия в инициализации должны вносить эффект не больше, чем изменение входных данных. Но думаю криптографы со мной не согласятся. Остается вопрос, зачем это вообще делать, стандартными функциями гораздо удобнее пользоваться , особенно если вдруг потребуется перенос на другой язык или еще что нибудь

Comment: @Mike, [вот статья](https://habrahabr.ru/post/168707/), в самом конце спойлер «Бонус». Последний абзац под спойлером явно напрягает параноиков :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Современные хеш-функции скорее всего не потеряют своей силы от такого преобразования, но делать такое строго не рекомендуется. В криптографии есть правило, не писать код криптографических алгоритмов самому, потому что неопытный может легко допустить очень серьезную ошибку.

Вместо этого вы можете использовать конструкцию `HMAC(hashfunc, pwd, message)`, и ваши случайные байты передавать как пароль.
Можно так же ваши случайные байты подставить в начало сообщения, как соль: `Hash(bytes + message)`. Эти 2 способа безопасны, потому что используются очень часто. А их результат не будет отличатся от того, что хотите сделать вы.

По поводу параноиков, во всех хеш-функциях то, чем заполняется начальный буфер, это не какие-то случайные константы, а строго определенные числа. Например, в SHA256 это первые 32 бита дробных частей квадратных корней первых восьми простых чисел (от 2 до 19).

В хабровской статье сомнению предана только одна функция, которая используется только в комбинации с другими функциями перемешивая бит. То, что в самой функции есть период, в этом нет ничего страшного.

Comment: Спасибо за пояснения и подсказки.